# Regex filter needed for tms_raw.YYYMMDDHHMMSS.out

Tags: python, regex

I have created a pattern:

`^(\W|^)tms_raw\.([0-9]{4})(-?)(1[0-2]|0[1-9])\2(3[01]|0[1-9]|[12][0-9])([0-2]{1})([0-3]{1}([0-5]{1})([0-9]{1})([0-5]{1})([0-9]{1}))(\.out)(\W|$)`

This tries to capture, `tms_raw.YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.out` string

background on, how did I create this pattern?

```
for matching YYYYMMDDHHMMSS        ^([0-9]{4})(-?)(1[0-2]|0[1-9])\2(3[01]|0[1-9]|[12][0-9])([0-2]{1})([0-3]{1}([0-5]{1})([0-9]{1})([0-5]{1})([0-9]{1}))$

for matching tms_raw.              ^(\W|^)tms_raw\.(\W|$)

for matching .out                  ^(\W|^)\.out(\W|$)
```

The pattern I have created does not capture, tms_raw.YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.out.
How can I combine the regex, I have made for matching individual elements, for matching something like `tms_raw.20080108235952.out`

Comment: `(\W|^)tms_raw\.([0-9]{4})(-?)([0-1]{1})([1-2]{1})([0-3]{1})([0-9]{1})([0-2]{1})[0-3]{1}([0-5]{1})([0-9]{1})([0-5]{1})([0-9]{1})\.out(\W|$)`

does the job for me however I am sure this is buggy as, I am getting system generated files, so getting a chance of getting invalid date is less, I need help in re factoring the code, thanks

Answer (score 1):

are the values going to change? 
I would use the python re.groups to decipher the parts.

```
r = re.compile("(?P<head>[\w]*?)\.(?P<time>[\d-]*)\.(?P<ending>[\w]{3,4})")
found = r.search("tms_raw.20080108235952.out")
#if found 
print( found.groupdict() )
```

**edit**

changing the grouping you can sub parse the time or just use time

```
myTime = datetime.datetime.strptime("20080108235952", "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
```

Comment: yes, the values are going to change,
`2008 is the year(YYYY),
01 is the month(MM),
08 is the day(DD),
23 is the hour(HH),
59 is the minute(MM),
52 is the second(SS),`

Comment: feed the `time` value from the found.groupdict() into the `strptime` to get a time object to use.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you want to match. If I read your original post correctly, you seem to want to match:

tms_raw.YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.out 

Is this correct? If that's the case, it seems like it would be relatively easy since tms_raw. and .out are constants. Since the number of digits won't change, it seems like you could easily do something like:

    \d{14}

which would give you the string for date/time. Is this what you need to parse?